# How to create a function that doesn't do anything in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, onclick

There is a component that must be build which must receive a function for onClick. The problem is that the function is not defined yet so it must receive some 'empty' function in order to pass the tests.

This is the code:

```
  <Button
    title='MyTitle'
    className='my-class-name'
    onClick={
      () =>
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        console.log('test')
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    }
  />
```

So I added a `console.log()` but eslint doesn't like it so the comments before and after it were added.

Is there a way to put a function that doesn't do anything just to pass the linting?

Comment: Try this `() => {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can just return null:

```
   <Button
        title='MyTitle'
        className='my-class-name'
        onClick={() => null}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<Button
    title='MyTitle'
    className='my-class-name'
    onClick={
      () => undefined
    }
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try returning [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) instead?

```
onClick={() => void 0}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. should `void0` be defined somewhere?